# SQL: using function as parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use a function to pass a parameter to a stored-procedure.

But this:

```
exec stpMySTP dbo.fn_MyFunction(123)
```

generates an error:

> *Incorrect syntax near '.'.*

Is it not possible to use a function when passing parameters to a procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant pass it directly to stored procedure. Declare first variable, set it to your function and then pass it to the procedure.

```
  DECLARE @pom [return type of function];
  SET @pom = dbo.fn_MyFunction(123);

  EXEC stpMySTP @pom
```